# Program started from trigger times out a db-access

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers, timeout

I call a programm from a trigger

```
SET @exeCall = 'C:\...\XMLResultValueSplitter.exe '+CAST(@resultID as nvarchar(40))
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @exeCall
```

The Programm reads the new, inserted line (by the resultId), splitts up several xmlvalues of it and inserts some values to another table.
But when executing it by the tirgger i get a timeout (starting it *normal*, it works of course)

Do you knwo how to handle this problem?

Thank you, Karl

Comment: Don't do the work in a trigger - queue the work in a table (or service broker queue, or something else suitable), and decouple this work (whatever it is) from the original transaction. Also, SQL Server has *some* XML handling features built in - are you sure this needs to be a separate executable?

Comment: The SQL Server XML handling features are far too weak for what I do. There are a lot of differnt things going on in the programm which can hardly be done in sql server